# Intelligence Sentence Comparison in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, nsstring, comparison

I need to do the intelligence Sentence comparison in Objective C.

The Detail's are  explained below.

I have one main string. I named it as "OriginalString"

```
                   NSString *OriginalString = @""HOW DID STUDENT EMILY DO TODAY";
```

Then I have many strings, that i need to compare with the Original String.They are

```
             NSString *CompareString1 = @"HOW DID EMILY DO "
             NSString *CompareSting  = @"HOW DID YOUR FATHER"
             NSString *CompareString2 = @"WHAT IS YOUR EMILY"
             NSString *CompareString3 = @"THIS IS THE FAST DO ONE"
             NSString *CompareString4 = @"THIS SEARCH EMILY EXAMPLE DO"
```

From these 5 CompareStrings ,i need to get the  string "HOW DID EMILY DO"  which is highest relative to the Original string(HOW DID STUDENT EMILY DO TODAY) .

Let me tell you one thing.

If i have an additional string in the group of CompareStrings As "HOW DID STUDENT DO TODAY"

So now i have the CompareStrings are

```
             NSString *CompareString1 = @"HOW DID EMILY DO "
             NSString *CompareSting  = @"HOW DID YOUR FATHER"
             NSString *CompareString2 = @"WHAT IS YOUR EMILY"
             NSString *CompareString3 = @"THIS IS THE FAST DO ONE"
             NSString *CompareString4 = @"THIS SEARCH EMILY EXAMPLE DO"
             NSString *CompareString4 = @"HOW DID STUDENT DO TODAY"
```

From these 6 CompareStrings ,i need to get the string "HOW DID STUDENT DO TODAY" which is highest relative to the Original string (HOW DID STUDENT EMILY DO TODAY)

I have looked the NSPredicate "comparison and like" methods. However i didn't found any way to do the process

Any help on figuring out this concept is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What are the rules you are using to decide the closest sentence? Or is that your question?

Comment: i didn't have any of rules. Just i need to get a " CompareString amoung them which is highest relative to my OriginalString "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like comp-sci homework.  It's sloppy and inefficient as hell, but it will work.  I'm sure somebody on here has a better idea to improve performance.

Break down your phrases that you want to search for into arrays of individual words:

```
NSArray *myWords = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

Now myWords is an array of each word (no spaces).  Then, build a predicate looking for each of the words:

```
int found = 0;
for (NSString* word in myWords) {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like[c] %@", word];
    BOOL ok = [predicate evaluateWithObject:originalString];
    if (ok) {
      ++found;
    }
}
```

When you are done, you'll end up with a `found` you can compare for each of the different phrases.  The one that is greatest matched the most words.

In this case, you'd end up counting like this:

`HOW DID STUDENT EMILY DO TODAY`

- "HOW DID EMILY DO " **4**
- "HOW DID YOUR FATHER" **2**
- "WHAT IS YOUR EMILY" **1**
- "THIS IS THE FAST DO ONE" **1**
- "THIS SEARCH EMILY EXAMPLE DO" **2**
- "HOW DID STUDENT DO TODAY" ***5***

Comment: What about if a word comes "DID DID DID DID".I think the solution will take always "DID DID DID DID" from the Comparison Strings while i type "HOW DID STUDENT EMILY DO TODAY

Comment: when searching you could prune uniques from your array by using filtering it through a unique comparator first

Answer (score 4):

Natural language parsing is a difficult topic, and it's unlikely you'll get good results with a simple string comparison approach.  I would suggest looking for a toolkit that operates at a higher level.  Lion and iOS 5 include a small level of support for this with the [NSLinguisticTagger class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSLinguisticTagger_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: i think we can't implemnt it in IOS 4.3.thank you for your excellent reply